# ActiveMQ DefaultMessageListenerContainer Why Only One Connection?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, activemq-classic

```
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${mq.activemq.host}" />
  <property name="userName" value="${mq.activemq.user}" />
  <property name="password" value="${mq.activemq.pass}" />
  <property name="maxThreadPoolSize" value="30" />
</bean>
<bean id="amqPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
  <property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="300" />
  <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000" />
</bean>
<bean id="queueListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqPooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="queueDestination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="queueAwareMessageListener" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="queueListenerTaskExecutor" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="5-30" />
</bean>
```

What is the relationship between `maxThreadPoolSize`, `maxConnections`, `maximumActiveSessionPerConnection`, and `concurrency`?

Why I set `maxConnections` = 10, but Listener only one Connector in the Connections, can't increase more?

The number of consumers is correct. It has 5 with initialization，and gradually increases with change.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line regarding the number of connections which will be used is determined by the `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which you have configured (since that is the only component here actually creating connections). As far as I can tell it will only ever create a *single* connection so using a connection pool here appears pointless. The `concurrency` parameter simply controls the concurrent number of *consumers* on the connection.

By setting `maxConnections` = 10 on the `org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory` you are just limiting the size of the connection pool. However, since the `queueListenerContainer` won't ever call `createConnection()` more than once it doesn't really matter.

You can read about the `maxThreadPoolSize` of the `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` in [the ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-deal-with-large-number-of-threads-in-clients.html).